# get the last updated mongo id from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

am working on push notifications using mongodb and nodejs.
I can see the newly added notifications (which are addede in Mongodb) in my browser
But, if I updated the record, the value is not updating in the browser

```
// if no error get reference to colelction named: 'notifications'
    db.collection('notifications', function(err, collection){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }

        // if no error apply a find() and get reference to doc
        collection.find().sort({
            $natural: -1
        }).limit(1).nextObject(function(err, doc) {
            // Rewind the cursor, resetting it to point to the start of the query
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }
            //  using tailable cursor get reference to our very first doc
            var query = {
                _id: {
                    $gt: doc._id
                }
            };
            var options = {
                tailable: true, 
                awaitdata: true, 
                numberOfRetries: -1
            };
            var cursor = collection.find(query, options).sort({
                $natural: 1
            });

            // This function will take cursor to next doc from current as soon as 'notifications' database is updated
            function next() {
                cursor.nextObject(function(err, message) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(message.message);
                    mdsok.volatile.emit('notification', message);
                    next();
                });
            }
            // what you need to do is: call it first time
            next();
        });
```

This is what i am doing in my code.

what should I do to update the value in the browser when I update the same in db.

Please help me . Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a tailable cursor implementation on what has to be a capped collection. You really should not be updating on a capped collection. For one, since it is "capped" the document may not exist. For two, "growing" a capped collection document is not allowed. They are meant to act as a "queue", therefore "insert only".

Comment: My actual requirement is, I am displaying some values in the browser which are fetched from the Mongodb database. If that value changed in db, then without refreshing my page, I need to display the updated value on the browser using sockets. Can anyone give me with a good example for this kind of requirement.

Comment: @NeilLunn, what you said is absolutely right! We can't update the capped collection. Leave about the capped collection. Now, I am not using the capped collection. I am using a normal collection and I have inserted some values in the collection. Now, I need to trigger the updated object whenever I update the object in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved upto some extent.

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
// NEVER use a Sync function except at start-up!
index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

// Send index.html to all requests
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    res.end(index);
});

// Socket.io server listens to our app
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

function getdata(){
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test", function(err, db) {
        var collection = db.collection('my_collection');

        var stream = collection.find({
            //'_id': new ObjectID('53eb6f2e75fd7ad00d000029')
            //_id: ObjectID.createFromHexString("53eb6f2e75fd7ad00d000029")
            }).stream();
        stream.on("data", function(item) {
            io.sockets.emit('db_status', {
                status: item.status
            });
            prev = item.status;
            console.log(prev);
        });
        stream.on("end", function() {
            console.log("Done loading data");
        });
    });
}


// Send current time every 5 secs
setInterval(getdata, 5000);

// Emit welcome message on connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.emit('welcome', {
        message: 'Welcome!'
    });            

    socket.on('i am client',function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});


app.listen(3000);
```

for every 5 secs, i am hitting the db and getting the value and displaying it in the browser.

To get the newly inserted object, we are using `.nextObject()` in `node.js`

Is there any way to get the updated object of the db as above in `node.js`.